# Why didn't Quinn send Rembrant and Wade to their version of Earth in Exodus?

Tags: sliders

This question contains spoilers, but hey, the series ended in 1999.

In Exodus Part 2, they have the coordinates of our earth stored in the other timer. Remmy asks Quinn to send them immediately, but he wants to help the people first, they get into a heated argument and they fight a little.

Why didn't Quinn take them there, and then returned by himself to finish helping? The timer was native to that world so he could safely set it to 2 minutes, go, leave them there and return later.

Is there an explanation or is it just a plot hole?

Comment: Quinn cannot set the timer on his own device, it was damaged early in Season 1 (see [Why would Quinn wait to Slide to a new reality?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/25291/2242)).  But I can't quite remember - did the people from Exodus have one they could set to anything, and is that the one you're asking about?

Comment: @Izkata yes, they had 2 timers. One from that world and their original one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Rembrandt knows breaking up the team is a bad idea, and that staying to help Exodus Prime is the right thing to do.

Long answer:

If you listen carefully to the dialog, Rembrandt says the following (emphasis mine):

> Not if *we* take *their* Timer and go now.

Rembrandt doesn't get angry until Quinn and the Professor refuse to leave. He already realizes that either they all go, or none of them go. They've only survived many of their adventures by working together (and a lot of luck). Separating the group hurts all of their chances of survival. Wade would likely stay with Quinn and the Professor, meaning he'd be going alone, and therefore he's blaming them for missing the chance to go home.

Secondly, there's a more practical reason why they don't split up. Even though Quinn seems convinced he found Earth Prime, his evidence *is* somewhat circumstantial. It could simply be "very close to Earth Prime" like we've seen before.

Therefore, if Quinn is wrong, Rembrandt could end up stranded unless they send him with their Timer, endangering the original three even more - if something goes wrong with the Exodus plan.

Rembrandt also knows they should stay behind and help, even if it doesn't want to admit it. He's trying to balance his emotions of wanting to go home with doing the right thing. Even if he did abandon the others to go home, he probably wouldn't be able to deal with the guilt for very long and he's been shown to have a strong conscience over the past three years.

Answer (score -1):

To keep the show going, but story wise he needed his friends they work as a team and a lot of times in the show they only win because they work together.