# Sliders 29 years rule

Tags: sliders

I've been re-watching the entire series and so far and I either missed it or haven't yet (currently mid season 4) seen a direct explanation to why they keep saying that if the sliders miss their sliding window, then the next one will be in 29 years... where did that number come from? Did I miss an episode or something?

Anyone has any ideas if it's just something they use to keep the plot "interesting" or if there is some actual canon explanation?

Comment: Actually, this other question has the answer to mine: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/25291/why-would-quinn-wait-to-slide-to-a-new-reality